# Trick to prevent child from stretching parent flexbox doesn't work on all browsers

Tags: css, flexbox

I have found a trick to prevent a child element from stretching its flexbox parent.

To do so, I use:

```
.magic {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}
.magic > div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 0; // this makes the trick
  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/bdgyNj

As you can see, the left column have scrollbars instead of stretching the entire flexbox.

But this thing doesn't work on Firefox (and probably on IE, I can't test it).

Do you guys know how to make it work cross browser?

Comment: This trick looks like a trick, not a normal behavior. You should probably use `display:table` here

Comment: CSS tables need lot of extra markup... It's weird that the new super powerful flexboxes can't handle a so simple task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the solution is:

**Don't use the trick!**

If you replace `height: 0;` with a simple `flex: 1 1 0`, it will work perfectly.
Just remember to not add the `%` symbol to the trailing `0` (which is the default behavior if you use the shorthand `flex: 1`).

Comment: This demo is offline and not working anymore though.